# My rails api not returning desired value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api-design

Hi I'm trying to write an api, but I'm having an issue with the controller not returning "hi"

Controller:

```
class ApisController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_api, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /apis
  # GET /apis.json

  def alertdump

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render html: 'hi' }
        format.json { render json: "hi" }
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :apis do
    collection do
      post 'alertdump/:fullalert', :action=> 'alertdump'
    end
  end
```

I'm getting instead this (which is the first element of the model 'api')

```
{"id":1,"created_at":"2016-06-07T15:05:17.897Z","updated_at":"2016-06-07T15:05:17.897Z"}
```

Comment: What request do you use and how are your routes defined?

Answer (score 0):

As you saying that you are writing the code for api than, you do not need respond with html request and you may try this for sending json response.

```
class ApisController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_api, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def alertdump
     render :json => 'Hi'
  end
end
```

Comment: still getting the same response

{"id":1,"created_at":"2016-06-07T15:05:17.897Z","updated_at":"2016-06-07T15:05:17.897Z"}

Comment: can you put you whole controller file.